# jQuery .val() returns different values depending on selector path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a large dynamically created table. It is 2+ columns with the first column being text and the second+ being values in text input fields. When the page loads, the input boxes have a default value. I want to be able to save the value when I make changes in the text field.

When I use `$("#ID_NAME").val()`, I get whatever value the user entered. If I drill down to the input field by other means, `.val()` gives me the default value when the page loaded. The page doesn't actually use any ids, I just added one for debugging.

I've posted a jsfiddle showing the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/GdjKp/1/

### HTML:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>test</legend>
<table id="menuSection">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>field</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row_1">
            <td>description</td>
            <td>
                <input id="test_id" type="text" value="default value"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</fieldset>Chane text value and click
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="run();"> the two elements found by jQuery will be in console.log() and the two values will pop up.
```

### JS  :

```
function run() {
    var a = $("fieldset");
    var b = $(a[0]).find("table > tbody > tr");
    var c = $(b[0]).children();
    var d = $(c[1].innerHTML);
    var result_1 = $(c[1].innerHTML);

    var result_2 = $("#test_id");
    console.log(result_1);
    console.log(result_2);

    alert(result_1.val());
    alert(result_2.val());
}
```

What is going on here?

**[EDIT]**
Here is the final working code

```
function save() {
    var cols = $("fieldset:first > table > thead > tr > th");
    var sections = $("fieldset");
    var ret = {};
    var sectionsTmp = {};
    var translation = {};

    for (var j=1; j < cols.length-1; j++) { //loop on language columns, skipping field names and delete columns (first and last columns)
        var lang = cols[j].innerHTML;
        sectionsTmp = {};

        for (var i=0; i < sections.length; i++) { //loop on sections/fieldsets
            var sectionName = $(sections[i]).children("legend")[0].innerHTML;
            var translations = $(sections[i]).find("table > tbody > tr");
            translation = {};

            for (var k=0; k < translations.length; k++) { //loop on translations in a section
                var translationId = translations[k].innerText.trim();
                var translationText = $(translations[k]).children().eq(j).find('input').val();
                translation[translationId] = translationText.replace(/'/g,'&apos;');
            }
            sectionsTmp[sectionName] = translation;
        }
        ret[lang] = sectionsTmp;
    }
    var url = '<?= $basePath?>/admin/save/item/translations/';
    var form = $('<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="' + url + '" method="post">' +
        '<input type="text" name="translations" value=\'' + JSON.stringify(ret) + '\' />' +
        '</form>');
    $('body').append(form);
    console.log(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: Why not give the inputs names or ids? it would be better to give the inputs ids or names so you can select them better like $("input[name=myinputname]") or better with id $("#myinputid"). selecting them the way you are now is inefficient.

Comment: In the actual code, the numbers are variables in nested loops.

Comment: so use '<input name="mybox'+number+'" when building and use $("input[name^=mybox]"), the ^= will grab any input that has a name beginning with mybox.

Comment: Yeah, I had considered that when I ran into the problem. Figured I would ask to learn more about jQuery. Is the way you propose better in some way? My thinking was that if I was going to be doing a number loop in either case, may as well not clutter up the html with IDs. Is there a reason to prefer iterating over selectors rather than children? Do they both return things in the proper order?

Comment: Well look at it this way you have 4 lines of code when you could just do 1 line. Plus your way runs multiple loops, one loop to get all elements matching `fieldset` then another to find elements inside that matching `table > tbody > tr`, then another to get all its children, thats at least 3 loops

Comment: No, no, sorry. I mean to say that in the code they are a[i], b[j], c[k].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually selecting the element in the case of result_1 - you're cloning it based on its html.

This line:

```
var result_1 = $(c[1].innerHTML);
```

is equivalent to this:

```
var result_1 = $('<input id="test_id" type="text" value="default value"></input>');
```

As you can see, result 1 has no relation to what's been typed into the input field - it's completely detached from the DOM.

Comment: Yup, that is indeed the problem. What would be the best way to do it instead?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  You can select items with jQuery using css selectors, if that's your goal - `$('fieldset table > body > tr > td').eq(1).find('input')` is equivalent to the route you were taking in your question

Comment: Ah, never saw the eq function before. Now I'm using that instead of newvar = $(varname[i]).children(); $(newvar[j]).children().val(); Thanks.